# C++ Why do 3 of these constructor calls work, but one doesn't?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following imbecile program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Baz {
public:
    Baz() {cout << "Baz ctor " << endl;}
    Baz(int i) : Baz() {}
    ~Baz() {cout << "Baz dtor " << endl;}
};

int main() 
{
    cout << "w" << endl;
    Baz w;

    cout << "x" << endl;
    Baz x();

    cout << "y" << endl;
    Baz y(1);

    cout << "z" << endl;
    Baz z = Baz();

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
w
Baz ctor 
x
y
Baz ctor 
z
Baz ctor 
Baz dtor 
Baz dtor 
Baz dtor
```

My question is thus: Why don't all these calls invoke the constructor?

I have been researching, but I have not found an explanation as to why the 2nd call does not invoke the constructor.  I would expect `Baz x()` to be equivalent to `Baz x = Baz()` the same way that `Baz y(1)` would be equivalent to `Baz y = Baz(1)`, there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Because it is function declaration instead of variable. Use `Baz x{};` instead

Comment: Or simply `Bar x`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement `Baz x();` declares `x` as a function with no parameters that returns a `Baz`. Change it to `Baz x{};` or `Baz x;` to call the default constructor.

Comment: What's need for empty braces? Also, it declares the function, not defines it.

Comment: fuzzything44, the first part of your answer is correct. However once you declared your own constructor, the class loss default constructor ability

Comment: @SergeyA, I edited the answer as per your suggestion. Is there a reason to prefer `Baz x;` over `Baz x{};`? I think there is a subtle difference between the two, but I can't remember.

Comment: The curly-bracket form performs value-initialisation; the other, default-initialisation.  Whether one is better than the other is debatable, but I always prefer to avoid uninitialised values :)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, there is. First of all, it's less typing! (good enough reason for me!). Second of all, `Baz x{}` would mean either aggregate initialization or default constructor call depending on `Baz` layout - while first thing is a default constructor fair and square. Why puzzle your readers?

Comment: @SergeyA Is that definitely the case? 8.5.4.3 ("List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows: — If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.") sounds to me like it suggests otherwise?

Comment: @SSJ_GZ, well, you need to keep reading. `To value-initialize an object of type T means: if T is a .. class type ... with either no default constructor ... or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized`